# Plotting individual responses for two-way repeated measures design with geom_path from ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, mixed-models, two-way

**I want to use `ggplot` and `geom_path` to plot individual responses measured in a completely balanced two-way repeated-measures experimental design.**

*I am able to generate the plot I want for data coming from a similarly structured mixed-model design*.

My datasets have similarly structured data. Each dataset has a response variable, "Response", and three independent variables.

In my first dataset (DF1), I have "Participant", "Gender", and "Condition". Three women and four men were included, making "Gender" a 'between-subjects' factor, and "Condition" a 'within-subjects' factor, and this is a mixed-model design, if I'm not mistaken.

```
DF1 <-
  data.frame(
    Response = c(3.2, 3.4, 3.5, 3.7, 3.2, 3.6, 3.5, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.3),
    Participant = as.factor(c(24, 33, 40, 24, 33, 40, 27, 30, 35, 42, 27, 30, 35, 42)),
    Gender = c("female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"),
    Condition = c("trained", "trained", "trained", "untrained", "untrained", "untrained", "untrained", "untrained", "trained", "untrained", "trained", "trained", "untrained", "trained"))
```

In my second dataset (DF2), I have "Participant", "Time", and "Condition". The same participants were involved in all combinations of "Time" * "Condition", making this a balanced 2-way repeated-measures design.

```
DF2 <-
  data.frame(
    Response = c(6.0, 6.4, 5.8, 6.3, 6.9, 6.2, 7.6, 7.2, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1, 7.1),
    Participant = as.factor(c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)),
    Time = as.factor(c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18)),
    Condition = c("Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Exercise"))
```

For my first dataframe (DF1), I can use `ggplot` and `geom_path` with the `group` and `color` aesthetics (`aes`) to get a plot that makes sense.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DF1,
       aes(x = Condition,
           y = Response,
           group = Participant,
           color = Gender)) +
  geom_path()
```

If I try to use the same setup for my second dataframe (DF2), the data are plotted, but in a way which does not make sense to me.

```
ggplot(DF2,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Response,
           group = Participant,
           color = Condition)) +
  geom_path()
```

I can use `facet_grid` to get a plot that makes sense, but this is not ideal because I want all of my data on a single plot, similar to what I can see when plotting DF1.

```
ggplot(DF2,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Response,
           group = Participant,
           color = Participant)) +
  geom_path() + facet_grid(.~Condition)
```

[Here is a .jpg of all of my plots side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztD49.jpg)

**Specifically I want:**

1. Time on the x-axis
2. One color for "Exercise" and a different color for "Nonexercise"
3. Two lines for each participant (one each for the "Exercise" and "Nonexercise" conditions)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to group by both `Condition` and `Paticipant`. A way to do that is using the `interaction()` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
DF2 <- data.frame(
        Response = c(6.0, 6.4, 5.8, 6.3, 6.9, 6.2, 7.6, 7.2, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1, 7.1),
        Participant = as.factor(c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)),
        Time = as.factor(c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18)),
        Condition = c("Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Nonexercise", "Exercise", "Exercise", "Exercise"))
ggplot(DF2) +
    geom_path(aes(x = Time, y = Response, group = interaction(Condition, Participant), color = Condition)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = Response, shape = Participant, color = Condition), size = 3)
```

I also added point with different shapes to improve clarity.

[image]

This is what you requested. If you are interested in my opinion, swapping the mapping would improve the plot even more (provided that the changes are consistent in others plots):

```r
ggplot(DF2) +
    geom_path(aes(x = Time, y = Response, group = interaction(Condition, Participant), color = Participant)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = Response, shape = Condition, color = Participant), size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Another solution I've found to help differentiate participants is altering `linetype` based on "Participant".

`ggplot(DF2,
       aes(x = Time,
           y = Response,
           group = interaction(Condition, Participant),
           color = Condition,
       linetype = Participant)) +
  geom_path()`